# how can I use of a class property in the nested function

Tags: php, function, class, oop

Why a class property is not accessible in the nested function ? So how do I use it?

```
class MyClass
{
    public $var = "I'm a class property!";

    public function Test()
    {
        function SubTest()
        {
          // I need to $this->var; here
        }
    }

}
```

I want to `echo` `$var` in the `SubTest()`. Is it possible ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "nested" function.... what you have is a function definition inside a method..... it means that the function `SubTest()` won't be defined unless the `Test()` method is called; but once it is defined, it will be a normal function in the __global__ (or possibly namespaced, if you're using namespacing) scope..... it is not a part of `MyClass` in any way, so doesn't inherit access to object properties

Comment: @MarkBaker ah, got it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a closure? `$this` is visible inside the closure since PHP 5.4.

And besides that you should not be defining a function inside a method like this. PHP functions are global, means they behave in exactly the same way as if they had been declared outside.

```
class MyClass
{
    public $var = "I'm a class property!";

    public function Test($str)
    {   

        $callback = function() use ($str)
        {
            print_r($this->var . " " .  $str);

        };

        return call_user_func($callback);
    }

}

$a = new MyClass();
$a->Test("My name is not Foo.");
```

Answer (score 1):

What about doing this?

```
<?php
class MyClass{

    public $var = "I'm a class property!";

    public function Test(){
        function SubTest(&$father){
            $father->var = 'something else';
            echo 'here ! '.$father->var.'<br />';
        }
        echo $this->var.'<br />';
        SubTest($this);
        echo $this->var.'<br />';
    }
}

$test = new MyClass();
echo $test->var.'<br />';
$test->Test();

?>
```

Gives this result:

```
I'm a class property!
I'm a class property!
here ! something else
something else
```

Comment: I want the output of this line: echo `$obj->var;` be `something else`.

Comment: @Sajad I've added an example to my answer, but I'm not really sure to understand what you are asking for... :-)

Comment: thanks, just can you add a point to your answer and explain this character `&` ?

Comment: This is a reference, so instead of copying the object when calling the function you pass its address

Comment: It's not, but it's the same concept